# MIPS BNE Instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a set of instructions as follows:

```
loop:
        sll  $t1, $t0, 2              # t1 = (i * 4)
        add $t2, $a0, $t1             # t2 contains address of array[i]
        sw $t0, 0($t2)                # array[i] = i

        addi $t0, $t0, 1              # i = i+1
        add $t4, $t4, $t0             # sum($t4) = ($t4 + array[i])

        slt $t3, $t0,   $a1             # $t3 = ( i < array_size)
        bne $t3, $zero, loop          # if ( i < array_size ) then loop
```

The `sll` instruction has an address (program counter) of `0x18`. `bne` has an address of `0x30`. MARS Simulator interprets the `bne` instruction as: `bne $11, $0, 0xfff9`. `0xfff9` is `-7`, meaning the instruction will jump 7 steps back. However, `sll` is six steps back. Does MIPS take into account the current instruction? Or does this happen because the program counter is incremented in the `fetch` stage, before the instruction finishes executing?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I will add "stride" as another possible reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On branch mips executes *two* instructions -- the branch instruction itself and the one following it (so called branch delay slot).

At the time branch takes effect, PC points to the instruction that *follows* the branch instruction itself, so -7 is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

On most architectures, branch targets are calculated from the instruction following the branch instruction (i.e: the PC is already advanced). IIRC ARM is the only common exception (there, the PC has advanced farther still, due to pipelining (of the original ARM implementation)).